RabbitMQ queue is building up messages even after I set the limit to 1
I'm new to this side of programming, so bear with my ignorance, please.
I have a flask webapp that calls a celery worker to perform a query and modify files with the returned data. those files are used for the site contents.  The issue that I'm having is that each time a client requests data from the site, it queues a task.  I've tried limiting the max-length and x-max-length to 1 and even 0, nothing.  tried setting TTL to 1 second, nothing.
I test this by going to my site, watching the total messages grow for that queue, then leave the site and watch 30 queued tasks complete sequentially.
any way around this? Am I misunderstanding something?
I've tried setting x-max-length to 0, 1, 2
I've tried setting max-length to 0, 1, 2
I've tried setting TTL to 1000, 5000
I've also tried making the query default and adding the Features with a policy, but still nothing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
